# Watch command line for string

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

(In bash) Is it possible to watch the output of a command line program and flag when a particular string occurs?

Basically my problem is that we have large build scripts that produce mountains of output to the console. I want to watch the console for say the word 'ERROR' and then alert me somehow.

I then know to go and watch the rest of the process/cancel it.

Answer (score 5):

Try it like this from command line:

```
<YOUR_BUILD_CMD> | grep ERROR
```

it will print out only ERROR when `<YOUR_BUILD_CMD>` outputs it. The `|` is the [pipe](http://www.linfo.org/pipes.html)  operator, and here is manual for [grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) command.

Comment: +1 for short and straightforward solution. but this will NOT give any output. because you have an ERROR in ERRROR. :D

Answer (score 5):

You can `grep` for the string, but you would need to store the original output of make, which can be done using `tee`. Example using mplayer to play a sound file as soon as an error occurs:

```
make 2>&1 | tee make.log | grep -lq ERROR && mplayer alert.wav
```

Answer (score 0):

I would pipe this through a while loop to check each line of output. eg

```
cmd &| while read line;do if [[ ${line} =~ ErrorRegex ]];then echo Error Detected: $line; else echo $line; fi;done
```

to break it down the "&|" redirects stderr and stdout to a while loop that reads 1 line of input at a time and puts it in the line variable. then a simple regex comparison looks for a error string and you can highlight that line or log it somewhere anything you like really go nuts. If its not matched with the error it will just print the output as normal.